# Error while building Angular to contribute to the project

Tags: angular

I'm trying to contribute to Angular, but once I forked the repository and tried to build it, I got the following error:

```
$ yarn bazel build packages/core
yarn run v1.22.17
$ C:\Users\DouglasCanevarollo\Desktop\angular\node_modules\.bin\bazel build packages/core
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
ERROR: C:/users/douglascanevarollo/_bazel_002625631/6mbkp73u/external/local_jdk/BUILD.bazel:134:10: @local_jdk//
:jre-lib: invalid label 'jre/lib/security/cacerts.2023-04-27T10?04?22' in element 139 of attribute 'srcs' in 'fi
legroup' rule: invalid target name 'jre/lib/security/cacerts.2023-04-27T10?04?22': target names may not contain 
'?'
```

I'm using Windows 10, by the way.

Did I miss something?

After I installed all the packages/dependencies and made the code changes for the issue I'm working on, I tried to follow the [Running tests locally](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6f5dabe0d25a5660b7c3001041449b4622dd8924/docs/DEVELOPER.md#running-tests-locally) section to test my changes in a sandbox application I have here. This was the first time the issue happened.

I tried to clean my `node_modules`, clean my Bazel configuration using `yarn bazel clean --expunge` and try again, but didn't get any luck. The `yarn build` above has the same issue, as the problem is in the build in fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who might face a similar problem, I managed to solve my issue by going to the local described in the message: **jre/lib/security/**. For some reason, the **cacerts** file name was created under an odd encoding: `cacerts.2023-04-27T10•04•22` (the dots). So I renamed this file to `cacerts.2023-04-27T10-04-22` and it worked!

P.S.: I really don't know why this file was created that way though...